# How do I return an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to write an app that takes the string that is entered into a text field and use it to call a thesaurus function. The function must return an array that contains synonyms to the string, but I seem to be having some syntax issues. Can someone lend an extra pair of eyes?

I already checked on the syntax and the scope of the variables, but I don't seem to understand where I'm getting it wrong.

```
var synonymsDictionary = ["swift" : ["abrupt", "expeditious", "hasty", "nimble", "quick", "rapid", "speedy", "sudden", "unexpected"],
                          "objective" : ["detached", "disinterested", "dispassionate", "equitable", "evenhanded", "nonpartisan", "open-minded", "unbiased"],
                          "calculate" : ["adjust", "appraise", "consider", "count", "determine", "forecast", "gauge", "guess", "measure", "multiply", "reckon", "subtract", "tally", "weigh", "work out"],
                          "create" : ["build", "conceive", "constitute", "construct", "design", "devise", "discover", "establish", "forge", "form"]]

func synonyms(for term: String) -> String {

    if let sameWords = synonymsDictionary[term] {
        print("These are the synonyms for \(term): \(sameWords)")
    } else {
        print("This word doesn't have any synonyms.")
    }
    let result = synonymsDictionary[term]
    return result
}
synonyms(for: "objective")
```

I should be getting an array with the synonyms for the term (string ) that I put in.Error

> Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]?' to return type 'String'

Comment: Fix the return type of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you return `String` but it should be an array `[String]` so try

```
func synonyms(for term: String) -> [String] {
   return synonymsDictionary[term] ?? []
}
```

Also hold a reference to the returned value

```
let res = synonyms(for: "objective")
print(res)
```

---

Since `synonymsDictionary` is a dictionary `[String:[String]]` then every value is of type `[String]` that can't be returned in a function that returns a value of type `String`

Comment: It seems like I can't return a string with the above code. The exact error is : Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]?' to return type 'String'

Comment: @pngan919 The compiler is complaining because you're contradicting yourself. You're trying to return multiple strings (in the form of an array of strings), but you're telling the compiler that the function should return a `String`. The two aren't compatible.